# Force network to overfit

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network

After designing a neural network, I red that its common practise training this network with a small amount of data. If it is overfitting - the current network architecture seems to be reasonable.

Do you agree with this procedure? Has someone any explanation for this behaviour.

A more specific case:

I am training my network with a dataset of 100 pictures. After 10 epochs, accuracy is converging to about 7%.

Training the same network with 100k pictures, the network converges to 7% accuracy after 1 epoch. But it does not go higher (in both cases)

Do you have a general explanation for this - without seeing the network?

Comment: With those values, your network architecture just seems completely inadequate. I somewhat agree that you should try to rapidly develop a better network aiming for high accuracy with a small data set, though I would take 1k pictures. It seems more robust than only 100, since you apparently have a reservoir of 100k dataset for further training and crossvalidation.

Comment: The thing is, we are training a RPN, there is no possibility of changing the network architecture

Comment: I don't know RPN specifically, but without changing the main architecture you probably have some room for modification, some hyperparameters, some algorithms choices for some layers?

Comment: Consider also checking on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the datascience link, I think I will ask there again